# Execute an ssh connection as a different user in Java

Tags: java, ssh, sudo, ssh-keys

I have a web server (jetty) that needs to perform operations on a remote host using ssh. The server runs as root and I would like it to stay that way.

On the webServer machine, as root, I can run `sudo -su user ssh user@sshServer.com`. This command opens an ssh session to sshServer using "user" as the user. The nice thing about this is that it starts the ssh session using user's ssh-keys file and does not require a password.

I would like to mimic this operation in Java. I've tried using several ssh libraries but couldn't get it to work. Whenever I try to connect as a different user, I am required to provide user's password. In other words, I can ask Java to logon to the sshServer as "user" but I can't ask Java to run the ssh-connection-command as "user". I believe that the keys file will be used only when executing the ssh-connection-command as "user".

Please note that user is my designated user for logging on to the sshServer. root itself doesn't have an ssh keys file and it is not a registered user that I can logon to sshServer with. I'd like to avoid storing user's password in the code or via some other obfuscation method. I also can't create other users whose passwords I can jeopardize in any way.

If someone knows of a library that will allow this or an alternate way to perform the operation, I'd be grateful.

Comment: did you try jsch?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'm currently using. If you know how to make it work, can you please share a short example? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're creating a big security hole. I wouldn't like to be a user on your machine. That said, java doesn't have "su"/"sudo" capability but if you don't care about security and your users aren't protecting their private keys with a passphrase, you can just directly use the private key file of the user (either copy it or point your library  at the user's private key file) - since you're running Java as root apparently. You haven't shown any code so it's hard to tell how to do that in your case.

Comment: use the shell chanell

Comment: Why not give root its own set of key  files and add those to the user on the remote machine? Basically, if anybody gains root privileges on your machine (which is highly likely given that you're running a web server under that user), they can get to the ssh machine's user. So just do it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSCH certificate based authentication:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

// Here privateKey is a file path like "/home/me/.ssh/secret_rsa "
// passphrase is passed as a string like "mysecr"
jsch.addIdentity(privateKey, passphrase);

session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 
// Or yes, up to you. If yes, JSch locks to the server identity so it cannot
// be swapped by another with the same IP.

session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("shell");
out = channel.getOutputStream();
channel.connect();
```

HTH,

Gal